# how to handle multiple keyword parameters in Django RestFramework URL

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

this my current url

url("sample/userid",views.sample)

I can query the data by userid or postid or x, or y parameters.

how to handle this efficiently in a single url

In the views, I will use kwargs to get the keywords, but not sure how to handle it in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#example

```
from django.urls import path

path('sample/<int:parm1>/<int:parm2>/<slug:parm3>/', views.sample),

or 

url(r'^sample/(?P<parm1>[0-9]{4})/(?P<parm2>[0-9]{2})/(?P<parm3>[0-9]{2})/$', views.sample),

as query string

url(r'^sample/', views.sample)

http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample/?parm1=John&parm2=Susan
```

Comment: I want that to be dynamic , say  I am passing  only user id or postid not both , how to handle that

Comment: url is deprecated in favor of re_path, also in row below you have URL ( case matters )

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
def sample(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if userid := request.query_params.get('userid'):
        print('do sth')
    if postid := request.query_params.get('postid'):
        print('do other sth')
    ...
```

Curl this url: `sample/userid?userid=v1&postid=v2`